# File based database for C++

Tags: c++, database

I want to use a database in my application. But it should not be a server-based database(like MySQL). Is there any file based database systems for C++ ? It is better if you can suggest a non-relational database. like XML file based ...

Comment: Have you considered [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)?

Comment: No. I want to try something different than rational databases. Is there any XML based databases ?

Comment: Do you mean *relational*? Maybe you could add it to the question.

Comment: A text-based datebase is more or less impossible. Normally it just acts as a backup for a memory based one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by file-based database. For example, Informix and MySQL keep their data in files.

However, you mentioned non-relational database, so I suggest you start with [couchdb](http://couchdb.apache.org/) or [mongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/).

[SQL lite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is an excellent relational database, and, if you are already used to SQL, would be a very good choice IMHO. I have not yet ventured into any production code with a non-relational database, but just looking at key structure makes me realize a lot of thinking above and beyond regular SQL database table design would be involved before I'd feel safe just throwing data into a non-relational database.

Answer (score 9):

Why, yes, there is. Try [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

Answer (score 4):

you can try this:
[ZWinSQL](http://www.it.fht-esslingen.de/~zimmerma/software/ZWinSql.htm)

> This C++ library provides a thin wrapper to use D. R. Hipp's SQLite, which is a single file based SQL database. ZWinSql does not much more than allow you to create, modify and query a database, contained in a single, local file, using standard SQL commands.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not looking for relational database maybe http://soprano.sourceforge.net is something that might suit you. it can be set up to work with local files directly